# Logger Writing to Multiple Files & Stderr/Stdout

Tags: go, logging

My goal is to create a logger that I can use to output to stdout (info logs) and stderr (error logs) as well as respective files (info.log) and (errors.log) all at the same time.

I am currently using loggers in Go like the following:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "io"
)

func main() {

    // Current method
    infoLog := log.New("./data/info.log", "INFO\t", log.Ldate|log.Ltime)
    errorLog := log.New("./data/errors.log", "ERROR\t", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)

    infoLog.Println("Hello INFO!")
    errorLog.Println("Hello ERROR!")

    // I've read about using io.MultiWriter like the following in order to write to stdout/stderr as well as a flat file at the same time
    f, err := os.OpenFile("./data/info.log", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error opening file: %v", err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    wrt := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, f)
    log.SetOutput(wrt)
    log.Println("Hello World!")
}
```

I'd like to basically take the formatting of `infoLog` and `errorLog` (like in my first logging solution) like `log.Ldate|log.Ltime` and apply it to the `io.MultiWriter`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

For logging info and error in file with standard format that other logging services such as filebeat, logstash and etc can understand it I suggest you to use `github.com/sirupsen/logrus`.
This package has `SetFormater` function to define format of output log. For example:

```
logrus.SetFormatter(&logrus.JSONFormatter{
        FieldMap: logrus.FieldMap{
            logrus.FieldKeyTime: "@timestamp",
            logrus.FieldKeyMsg:  "message",
            logrus.FieldKeyFunc: "func",
            logrus.FieldKeyFile: "file",
        },
    })
```

and you can define file for logging. For example:

```
file, err := os.OpenFile("payment_logs.log", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
```

And set log is very easy and standard:

```
logger.Info("This is an info message")
logger.Warn("This is a warning message")
logger.Error("This is an error message")
```